# How and when can I use PPMs that weren't built in in ActivePerl 5.18?

Tags: perl, activeperl

I installed ActivePerl 5.18 and discovered that none of the PPM modules were available for download. Poking around on the forums I saw that they said there were delays with module porting.

I downloaded 5.16 for now, and was wondering two things:

1. Is it safe to just copy 5.16 modules into 5.18? Is it known which ones aren't compatible?
2. if not safe, is there a rough ETA on when Active Perl would support all the PPMs in 5.18

Comment: 1. No. Any that installs files to the "arch" folder. Be wary of modules with dependencies that can't be copied over. 2. No idea.